# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Insert Fields into Word Document

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, dynamics-crm

I am trying to create a word document to be housed the Microsoft Dynamics CRM document library, that when opened, will insert the client name and client address fields from Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The client name and address fields must be those of client currently being viewed.

I have tried attempting this via Macros in Word, but am unable to get a reference to the current sharepoint context in VBA.

Also, I have also tried this with word documents containing List fields, but so far without success.

Does anybody know if what I'm attempting is even possible?

All suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Im using this one DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll to create documents, and saving them as notes i guess you should be able do wha you want with it.

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124
```